# Updating a Provider from a StreamProvider

Tags: flutter

I have a StreamProvider connected to Firebase, and another Provider/ChangeNotifier with functions to process the data from StreamProvider in different ways depending on app state. For this reason, whenever new data comes from the StreamProvider, I would like to immediately send it to be stored in Provider/ChangeNotifier, where it can be easily processed when the app state changes.

The problem: I don't know the best way to send the result of StreamProvider to the Provider/ChangeNotifier.

My temporary solution: Within the StreamProvider function, I can send the result to the other Provider by doing something like below, but note that I have to use 'listen: false'. Otherwise, I get an error like "Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree".

This seems like it is not the best solution because I have to set a variable to Provider.of(context) at all the places where I need to Consume the Provider, even though I don't actually need the result of the StreamProvider in these widgets. But without these variables defined, the widgets depending on the StreamProvider and Provider would not rebuild.

I'd like to know if there is a better way to accomplish this.

**From the stream defined for the StreamProvider:**

```
return ref.snapshots().map((items) {

      // Sending the result to the other Provider
      var appData = Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false);
      appData.setVariable(items);

      return items;

}
```

Comment: Provider is usually good for simple problems (some values that don't have large effect on app state) but when it gets complicated why don't you think of using Bloc?
take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdUBV7AWL2U

Comment: I think that will be probably be the best solution. I learned about bloc recently and it seems more capable than provider. I've gone through a few other state management methods before reaching this point, consistently finding limitations that require a different method to be used. Maybe bloc will be my last stop.